# PHP - get single file based on user

Tags: php, arrays, pdf, for-loop, output

I'm having trouble getting my code to work the way I want.

I'm using `scandir` to get all files from the directory. This gives me a list with pdf files linked to a product, but the problems comes with the posibllity of pdf files multiple languages. Like so:

- 1096_EN.pdf
- 867_PT.pdf
- 914_EN.pdf
- 914_NL.pdf

Before `_` is ID and after language. And I want the user to only see one file per product.

my code looks likes this:

```
$files =  scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $file) 
{
    $exp_file = explode("_", $file);

    // check file for given ID
    if($exp_file[0] == $_GET['iD']){

        // check file for userlanguage

        if($exp_file[1] == $lang){
            echo $file;
        }
        // check file in english
        elseif($exp_file[1] == "EN"){
            echo $file;
        }
        // return available file in other language
        else{
            echo $file;
        }
    }
}
```

In case of 914 and NL the code returns two files. In case of 914 and PT i only get 1 file, `914_EN.pdf` and in case of 867 and NL there will be zero files.

What is the best way to filter my files and return the best matched file? I personally think the error is in the `for` loop, but I cant find a proper way out..

thanks

Comment: Use a temp array that is filled with the `for` scan instead of directly echoing out. After the `for`, print the first array index that is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by the following:

```
if(glob($_GET['iD']."_".$_GET['t']."*.pdf"))
{
    $file = glob($_GET['iD']."_".$_GET['t']."*.pdf");
    echo $file[0];
}
else 
{
    if(glob($_GET['iD']."_EN*.pdf"))
    {
        $file = glob($_GET['iD']."_EN*.pdf");
        echo $file[0];
    }
    else
    {
        $file = glob($_GET['iD']."*.pdf");
        echo $file[0];
    }
}
```

No more looping, just checking for different files with wildcards. Works like a charm. I.m.o. much cleaner with larger lists of files..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have just the single items, you should keep a backlog of which you have already processed, as the foreach loop will go from for example 914_EN.pdf to 914_NL.pdf, while the checks have already been completed for 914_EN.pdf, so when you get to 914_NL.pdf, it just reruns the checks and thinks it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

if working with multiple same values, you can first cleanse the array to get what you wanted. You can take a look at this, if this what you want. Cheers!

```
$files =  array("1096_EN.pdf", "867_PT.pdf", "914_EN.pdf", "914_NL.pdf");
    $new_exp_file = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $exp_file = explode("_", $file);
            $new_exp_file[] = $exp_file[0];
        }

        $new_exp_file_arr_ = array_values(array_unique($new_exp_file));
        for($i = 0, $file_ctr = count($new_exp_file_arr_); $i < $file_ctr; $i++) {
            if($new_exp_file_arr_[$i] == "914") {
                echo $new_exp_file_arr_[$i] . "<br>";
                echo "<ul>";
                    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        $exp_file = explode("_", $file);
                        if($new_exp_file_arr_[$i] == $exp_file[0]) {
                            echo "<li>" . $exp_file[1] . "</li>";
                        }
                    }
                echo "</ul>";
            }

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work for me? Using a regex probably not as efficient as the above methods though.

```
$_GET['iD'] = 1096;

$ptn = "^((\d+)\_([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+))^";
$aFiles = array('1096_EN.pdf','867_PT.pdf','914_EN.pdf','914_NL.pdf');
$lang = "EN";

foreach ($aFiles as $sFileName) 
{

    preg_match($ptn, $sFileName, $aFileParts);
    var_dump($aFileParts);


    // check file for given ID
    if($aFileParts[2] == $_GET['iD']){

        // check file for userlanguage
        if(strtolower($aFileParts[3]) == strtolower($lang)){
            echo $sFileName;
            break;
        }

        // return available file in other language
        else{
            echo $sFileName;
        }
    }

}
```